# Enumerating a pack

Tags: c++, parameter-pack

I don't quite understand the base trick from Daisy Hollman's talk:

https://youtu.be/15etE6WcvBY?t=2670

Enumerating a pack using c++20 lamdas with explicit template arguments.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Function, typename ...Ts>
void enumerate_pack(Function f, Ts... args) {
  [&]<std::size_t... Idxs>(std::index_sequence<Idxs...>) { (f(Idxs, args), ...); }
  (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>{});
}

int main() {
  enumerate_pack([](std::size_t i, auto arg) { std::cout << i << ": " << arg << "\n"; }, "hello",
                 42, "world", 73.2);
}
```

My problem with it is this part:

```cpp
  (f(Idxs, args), ...);
```

This looks to me like we are "passing a **type** to a function". OK, we are expanding the pack so it's a single type and not the whole pack, but it's still a "type", to my eyes. And even more confusingly, the second argument `args` is the name of a local variable - again a pack, but a variable nonetheless. The usage of `args` makes much more sense to me.

I would have thought the syntax should be:

```cpp
  [&]<std::size_t... Idxs>(std::index_sequence<Idxs...> idxs) { (f(idxs, args), ...); }
```

Note that I have now given a name to the parameter pack (`idxs`) and used that. This doesn't compile.

Is the syntax here just a little baroque, or is there something deeper I am missing?

Comment: `Idxs` is a _non-type_ template parameter for the lambda

Comment: @Mat
OK, yes. That's so true! I guess the confusing part for a moment was that that non-type parameter was actually being deduced based on the (pack) type of the ACTUAL parameter passed to the function?? ie the lambda is not being called with `<>` angle brackets, but instead the "type" of the "non-type template parameter", which is the sequence, is being deduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
f(Idxs, args), ...
```

Because both `Idxs` and `args` are parameter packs, expands to:

```
f(0, args0), f(1,args1), .....
```

If you replace `Idxs` with a `std::index_sequence<Idxs...>` then it isnt a pack, it does not expand and `f(std::index_sequence<Idxs...>, argX)` is the wrong signature for `f`. There is no overload for `f` that takes a `std::index_sequence<Idxs...>` as first paramter.

The only purpose of the index sequence is to get your hands on the indices. The index sequence itself is not used, hence needs not be named.

Comment: Yes, and as Mat says above `Idxs` is a NON type template parameter pack, ie it's a set of compile time integer VALUES... not a set of types, as in many other "normal" parameter packs.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock yes `<std::size_t... Idxs>` is a pack of `std::size_t`s

Comment: @OliverSchönrock I understand that you are in the process of learning, but I recommend to not consider non-type arguments as "not normal". They are different but not less "normal". I am also not sure if they are that much less common

Comment: That's why I put "normal" in quotes ;-). I am quite familiar with NTTPs and use them often. I am less familiar with NTTP packs, and that's what caused the confusion here. It is a little baroque to pass a complex type (the sequence), then use a template to deduce this complex type in terms of a pack of NNTPs, which we then use for expansion...

Comment: @OliverSchönrock thats exactly what `index_sequence` is made for. See here for more details and examples: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: Yes, well familiar with that page. Just not spent enough time with its usage...

Answer (score 1):

The lambda is being called with a single parameter:

```
(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>{})
```

If you open the documentation for `std::make_index_sequence`, it will explain that it produces a `std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3>`, for example, if `sizeof...(args)` is 4.

So, in this example, the parameter to the lambda is a `std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3>`.

The lambda declaration uses a template to deduce `std::size_t... Idxs` as `0, 1, 2, 3`, and each one of these get fed, one at a time, to `f()` as its first parameter. The call to `f()` simultaneously expands two parameter packs, the parameters to these functions, and the one that's deduced from the call to the lambda.

Comment: Yes, that makes it clearer, thank you. 
And as Mat says in a comment above `Idxs` is a NON type template parameter pack, ie it's a set of compile time integer VALUES... not a set of types, as in many other "normal" parameter packs. So my "distraction" with "passing a type" is just incorrect...